# Component / design to pass voltage when two inputs have continuity

Tags: led

I am trying to make a test box that you will plug up a RJ45 ethernet cable into and it will have 4 green LEDs that will light up independently if each of the 4 pairs of the ethernet cable are shorted/have continuity. The ethernet cable will not have voltage across it. I need each color pair in the cable (blue/green/orange/brown) to trigger the LED to light if it has continuity. I am not sure how to accomplish this since there won’t be voltage (or any signal) on the cable.  It will either be in an open or shorted state. I plan to use a 9V battery inside the box to power the LEDs.

Note: This is not being used for any network type application. It’s just checking for a closed or open state on an RJ45 connector.

Comment: Doesn't much matter what the end use is, the problem is the same. You will need to apply a voltage to test it. Try this link, it gives you a complete solution. https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/tarantula3/diy-lan-cable-tester-with-or-without-arduino-3c41d7 You can tweek it to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! I appreciate it!

Comment: It would require a specially engineered jack, but one technique is just to split the contact into two contact points so you can test for continuity without injecting a signal into the attached wire.  Is the goal to test for the presence of a connection in the jack or to test the wires themselves?

Comment: You can purchase a network cable tester for less then $10.00, eBay had one for less then $5.00 shipping included. This is probably much less then the cost of making one.

Comment: I should have included this info in my initial posting. This application will be to test alarm points that connect through a 66 punch down block and feed to an alarm module at work. The different alarms that feed to the alarm module all come from different sources (magnetic switch for a door, HVAC unit, DC power plant alarms from an alarm board, and various pieces of equipment). All of the alarm points are set to be normally closed when good and they go open when the alarm is active. These alarms all feed back to an alarm module over cat-5 and plug into the RJ-45 jacks on the module.

Comment: Given how each of these alarm points feed to different equipment alarms, I can’t easily access the far end equipment to be able to short it out and test.  I would like this device to keep each LED lit solid to show that it’s a good short, otherwise I know if the LED is not lit, there is an issue with that alarm point.